# Problema com programa de calculadora

Tags: c

Bom dia , gostaria de saber, porque o meu programa de calculadora não esta printando o valor das operações??Segue abaixo o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{

    float A, B;
    char op;

    scanf("%f", &A);
    scanf("%c", &op);
    scanf("%f", &B);

    switch('op')
            {

            case 43 : printf("%f", A + B);
            break;

            case 45 : printf("%f", A - B);
            break; 

            case 42 : printf("%f", A * B);
            break;

            case 47 : printf("%f", A / B);
            break;

            }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mete `default` no `switch`! Liga o máximo de warnings do teu compilador e toma-lhes atenção!

Comment: Remova as aspas do 'op': `switch(op)`

Comment: Ja removi as aspas e continua com o mesmo problema

Comment: no `default` do `switch`, imprime o valor de `op`.

Comment: Como disse em minha resposta não é possivel colocar strings no case.

Answer (score 8):

Para além do problema do `switch('op')`, que deveria estar sem aspas como já mencionado nos comentários, o seu `scanf` não está consumindo a entrada da maneira que você imagina. Vamos testar por exemplo a soma de `1.0` e `2.0`. Você digita:

> `1.0`<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
>   `+`<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

E o programa termina, sem pedir o terceiro número! Isso porque o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> após o primeiro float é considerado o caractere que você estava esperando no segundo `scanf`. Se você digitar a expressão toda numa só linha, o programa [funciona normalmente](http://ideone.com/LQK0no):

> `1.0+2.0`<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Uma solução simples (mas não muito bonita) para ler linha a linha é colocar um [`getchar`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdio.h/getchar) após a leitura do primeiro float:

```
scanf("%f", &A);
getchar();
scanf("%c", &op);
scanf("%f", &B);
```

<sup>http://ideone.com/Guc1Kj</sup>

Ou, como sugeriu o @JJoao, simplesmente acrescentar um espaço no que é esperado pelo segundo `scanf`:

```
scanf("%f", &A);
scanf(" %c", &op);
scanf("%f", &B);
```

<sup>http://ideone.com/2n5uMO</sup>

Comment: @JJoao [Funciona mesmo](http://ideone.com/2n5uMO), e fica bem mais limpo. Vou mencionar isso na resposta, se me permite. Eu sei pouquíssimo de C...

Comment: Força! (esta questão é manhosa e raramente aparece descrita de modo que se entenda)

Answer (score 3):

Desculpem responder outra vez mas agora de um modo mais de acordo com o que o OP
pretende.

1. `case 43` --> `case '+'` torna as coisas mais legíveis
2. `scanf` retorna uma valor (número de elementos lidos) -- pode ser usado para validação
3. no formato `scanf` os espaços significam avançar zero ou mais brancos (espaços e "\n") o que é muito importante para a leitura do operador.
4. Simetrias verticais na indentação torna as coisas mais legíveis

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
   float A, B;
   char op;

   if (scanf("%f %c %f", &A, &op , &B) == 3)
       switch(op) {
          case '+' : printf("%f", A + B); break;
          case '-' : printf("%f", A - B); break; 
          case '*' : printf("%f", A * B); break;
          case '/' : printf("%f", A / B); break;

          default : printf("???\n"); 
      }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Postar outra resposta foi a atitude correta, já que são duas abordagens diferentes do problema.

Comment: @bfavaretto, estou a "falar" de mais, mas apesar de um pouco redundante acabei por escrever esta por causa dos espaços no scanf (que é importantissiomo e quase ninguem conhece)

Answer (score 1):

Se não me engano o switch de `C` é somente de valores primitivos inteiros (isso pode ter mudado nas ultimas versões) outro detalhe em `char op` você esta atribuindo dois caracteres logo o ultimo não será pego então mesmo que fosse possível pegar char em switch nunca casará com um `case` para que possa pegar dois ou mais caracteres você deveria declarar um array de caracteres

char op[3]; // as duas primeiras posições para o `4` e `3` e a ultima posição para o `/0`

Assim funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{

    float A = 3;
    float B = 9;
    int op = 43;

    //scanf("%f", &A);
   // scanf("%c", &op);
   // scanf("%f", &B);

    switch(op)
            {

            case 43 : printf("%f", A + B);
            break;

            case 45 : printf("%f", A - B);
            break; 

            case 42 : printf("%f", A * B);
            break;

            case 47 : printf("%f", A / B);
            break;

            }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: 43 é o ASCII code para +, lol

Answer (score 1):

Uma das maneiras mais cómodas de escrever C é gerá-lo.
Nesta caso com `flex`.

A estrutura típica dum programa `flex`é:

```
%%
regExp    {ação C}
...
%%
```

No nosso caso o ficheiro `calc.fl` é:

```
F   [ ]*[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[ ]*
%%
  float A, B;

{F}\+{F}    { sscanf(yytext,"%f + %f",&A, &B);   printf("%f\n", A+B); }
{F}\*{F}    { sscanf(yytext,"%f * %f",&A, &B);   printf("%f\n", A*B); }
{F}\/{F}    { sscanf(yytext,"%f / %f",&A, &B);   printf("%f\n", A/B); }
{F}\-{F}    { sscanf(yytext,"%f - %f",&A, &B);   printf("%f\n", A-B); }
\n          {}

%%
```

Para compilar:

```
flex -o calc.c calc.fl
cc  -o calc cal.c -lfl
```

Esta solução aceita perguntas repetidamente até que CTR-D; o utilizador pode inserir espaços e new-lines livremente (espaços no formato `sscanf`).

Comment: Qual é o código C que isso gera? Acho que poderia fazer parte da resposta.

Comment: @bfavaretto, O código gerado é complicadissimo -- o flex cria uma função yylex com um automato deterministico (3 ou 4 vectores  matrizes) com a união de todas as expreg usadas, e optimizado até à exastão: não é nada legível, mas e estupidamente eficiente...

Answer (score 0):

Posso estar errado mas eu não encontrei nenhum valor sendo passado para entrar no switch.
Fiz dessa forma e funcionou:

```
int main (void)

{

float A, B;
int op;

printf("Entre com a opcao: ");
scanf("%d", &op);
printf("Entre com o valor de A: ");
scanf("%f", &A);
printf("Entre com o Valor de B: ");
scanf("%f", &B);



switch(op)
        {

        case 43 : printf("%f", A + B);
        break;

        case 45 : printf("%f", A - B);
        break; 

        case 42 : printf("%f", A * B);
        break;

        case 47 : printf("%f", A / B);
        break;

        }

        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: o meu professor pediu para que op seja do tipo char